# How should I deal with numbering of claims?

Tags: numbering, theorems

I've defined my claim in the following way: `\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}` The numbering works perfectly fine, but what should I do in cases when I want to skip some numbering. That is:

**Claim 1:** ....

**Claim 2:** ....

**Claim:** //just claim without numbering!

**Claim 3:**....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can declare an un-numbered claim by

```
\newtheorem*{claim*}{Claim}
```

The starred version produces no number. When you don't want numbering use

```
  \begin{claim*}
    Some claim with no number
  \end{claim*}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}
\newtheorem*{claim*}{Claim}
\begin{document}
  \begin{claim}
    Some claim
  \end{claim}
  \begin{claim}
    Some claim
  \end{claim}
  \begin{claim*}
    Some claim with no number
  \end{claim*}
  \begin{claim}
    Some claim
  \end{claim}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd call it `claim*`